# SystemEvents.SessionSwitch doesn´t fire in a c# wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, events, desktop

i have a small c# wpf application. The application starts hidden and i use the systemtray to show the main window. I would like to do some actions when a user unlocks the desktop. I use the SystemEvents.SessionSwitch event, bit the event doesn´t fire. I've read some posts and this event seems to be the right one for WPF applications, but it doesn't work. Are there perhaps DLLs missing or is the call to register the event too late? Is there a problem with the UI Thead?

My Application Code:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon _notifyIcon;
    private bool _isExit;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += new Microsoft.Win32.SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch);

        MainWindow = new MainWindow();
        MainWindow.Closing += MainWindow_Closing;

        _notifyIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
        _notifyIcon.DoubleClick += (s, args) => ShowMainWindow();
        _notifyIcon.Icon = CiGCoachingClient.Properties.Resources.MyIcon;
        _notifyIcon.Visible = true;

        CreateContextMenu();
    }

    private void CreateContextMenu()
    {
        _notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip =
          new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip();
        //_notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("MainWindow...").Click += (s, e) => ShowMainWindow();
        _notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Exit").Click += (s, e) => ExitApplication();
    }

    private void ExitApplication()
    {
        _isExit = true;
        MainWindow.Close();
        _notifyIcon.Dispose();
        _notifyIcon = null;
    }

    private void ShowMainWindow()
    {
        if (MainWindow.IsVisible)
        {
            if (MainWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
            {
                MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            }
            MainWindow.Activate();
        }
        else
        {
            MainWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            MainWindow.Show();
        }
    }

    private void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_isExit)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MainWindow.Hide(); // A hidden window can be shown again, a closed one not
        }
    }

    private void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock)
        {
            //I left my desk
            Console.WriteLine("i left my desk");
        }
        else if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock)
        {
            //I returned to my desk
            Console.WriteLine("i returned to my desk");
        }
    }
}
```

What could be the reason for this? Is there a error in the code?

Regards
Sascha

Comment: `Console`? Try `Debug` instead and observe Output window while pressing [win]+L and then logging back. Works for me.